# recycler view position

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am new to android development.I have a recyclerview with Viewholder for displaying photo.I have implement **like** feature in my app but only problem that I am facing is when I add a **like** on the photo the **like** does not show on photo I liked instead it is showing **like** on another photo that is down below,when I see in firebase database it looks fine but it does not display in the right position in recycler view.

I think it is not updating position how can I solve this?

this is my adapter class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
// mHolder = holder;
photo = moviesList.get(position);
//  final VideoHolder viewHolder2 = (VideoHolder)holder;
int viewType = getItemViewType(holder.getAdapterPosition());
switch ( viewType ) {
    case IMAGE_TYPE:
        PhotoHolder photoview = (PhotoHolder) holder;
        mPhotoHolder = photoview;
        getCurrentUsername();
        getLikesPhotoString();
        final ImageLoader imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getImage_path(),photoview.image);
        photoview.mHeart.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
            @Override
            public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                addNewPhotolike(mPhotoHolder);
            }
            @Override
            public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                removePhotolike(mPhotoHolder);
            }
        });
        photoview.Star.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
            @Override
            public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {

            }
            @Override
            public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
            }
        });
        break;
    case VIDEO_TYPE:
        final VideoHolder viewHolder2 = (VideoHolder)holder;
        mVideoHolder = viewHolder2;            
        break;
}


}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return moviesList.size();
}
public Photo getItem(int position) {
return moviesList.get(position);
 }
@Override
public int getItemViewType ( int position ) {
int viewType;
if (moviesList.get(position).getType_post().contains("Photo")) {
    viewType = IMAGE_TYPE;
} else{
    viewType = VIDEO_TYPE;
}
return viewType;
}
```

**this is were photo like is added to firebase**

```
private void addNewPhotolike(TestAdapter.PhotoHolder holder, final int position){
    Log.d(TAG, "addNewlike: adding new like ");
    String newLikeID = mReference.push().getKey();
    Likes likes = new Likes();
    likes.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
            .child(getItem(position).getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(likes);
    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
            .child(getItem(position).getUser_id())
            .child(getItem(position).getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(likes);
    holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(true);
    HashMap<String ,String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
    notificationData.put("from",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    notificationData.put("type","likes");
    notificationData.put("photo_desc",getItem(position).getDescription());
    holder.mNotification.child(getItem(position).getUser_id()).push().setValue(notificationData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
          //  getLikesString(mHolder);
            getLikesPhotoString(mPhotoHolder,position);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
          //  getLikesString(mHolder);
            getLikesPhotoString(mPhotoHolder,position);

        }
    });

}
```

This is my code where **like** is retrieved from firebase and shown in text.

```
private void getLikesPhotoString(final TestAdapter.PhotoHolder holder, final int postion){
Log.d(TAG, "getLikesString: getting likes string");
try{
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    reference.keepSynced(true);
    Query query = reference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
            .child(getItem(postion).getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes));
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            holder.usersPhoto = new StringBuilder();
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                Query query = reference
                        .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                        .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                        .equalTo(singleSnapshot.getValue(Likes.class).getUser_id());
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found like: " +
                                    singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());
                            holder.usersPhoto.append(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());
                            holder.usersPhoto.append(",");
                        }
                        String[] splitUsers =  holder.usersPhoto.toString().split(",");

                        if( holder.usersPhoto.toString().contains(currentUsername + ",")){
                            holder.likephotobycurrentUser = true;
                        }else{
                            holder.likephotobycurrentUser = false;
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: likes string: " +  holder.mLIkePhotoString);
                        //  setupwidjets();

                        int length = splitUsers.length;
                        if(length == 1){
                            holder.mLIkePhotoString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0];
                        }
                        else if(length == 2){
                            holder.mLIkePhotoString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                    + " and " + splitUsers[1];
                        }
                        else if(length == 3){
                            holder.mLIkePhotoString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                    + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                    + " and " + splitUsers[2];

                        }
                        else if(length == 4){
                            holder.mLIkePhotoString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                    + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                    + ", " + splitUsers[2]
                                    + " and " + splitUsers[3];
                        }
                        else if(length > 4){
                            holder.mLIkePhotoString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                    + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                    + ", " + splitUsers[2]
                                    + " and " + (splitUsers.length - 3) + " others";
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: likes string: " + holder.mLIkePhotoString);
                        //setup likes string
                     //   setupLikePhotostring(holder, holder.mLIkePhotoString);
                        holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(true);
                        if (holder.likephotobycurrentUser){
                            holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(true);
                        }else {
                            holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(false);
                        }
                        holder.likes.setText(holder.mLIkePhotoString);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                holder.mLIkePhotoString = "";
                holder.likephotobycurrentUser = false;
                //setupwidjets();
            //    setupLikePhotostring(holder,holder.mLIkePhotoString);
                if (holder.likephotobycurrentUser){
                    holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(true);
                }else {
                    holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(false);
                }
                holder.likes.setText(holder.mLIkePhotoString);

                holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}catch (NullPointerException e){
    Log.e(TAG, "removeStar: NullPointer"+e.getMessage());
    holder.mLIkePhotoString = "";
    holder.likephotobycurrentUser = false;
   // setupLikePhotostring(mPhotoHolder,holder.mLIkePhotoString);
    if (holder.likephotobycurrentUser){
        holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(true);
    }else {
        holder.mHeartPhoto.setLiked(false);
    }
     holder.likes.setText(holder.mLIkePhotoString);
}

}
```

Comment: you are not getting position of photo

Comment: Post your adapter code

Comment: okk ...please wait

Comment: soo see bro..I have the full code

Comment: You need to provide position of which button is clicked

Comment: This type of `RecyclerView`-related problem where one item has some action expected but another item gets the action is usually due to not resetting some view holder fields in `onBindViewHolder()`. For instance, where do you set `mHeartPhoto`? Can you post that code and maybe what the contents of `mHeartPhoto` are?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
photo = moviesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

to

```
photo = moviesList.get(position);
```

where position variable is same as we got in below function

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position);
```

And also change `holder.getAdapterPosition()` to `position` in `onBindViewHolder(...)` function.

Comment: its not error . its not crashing but it is not showing like on liked post ..instead it showing on another photo

Comment: Show `addNewPhotolike()` method please

Comment: no there is no problem in add new photo like() ..it is adding like perfectly to database.. if you still want to see ..I'll  show you..I have edited see